# Basic arrow keys and page up/down usage in intellij on mac

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

What are the equivalent keys for page up/ page down in intellij on os x? Option arrow up/down is not doing anything AFAICT.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to `Preferences` | `Keymap` and assign any hotkey you like to **Move Up/Down and Scroll**:

[image: scroll]

Comment: Unexpected default arrow key handling is a persistent nuisance: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206345169/comments/206919495.  Also be aware that numeric keyboard arrows aren't differentiated (from other arrow keys) in the settings dialog, but it does know the difference.

Comment: it is not page up/down, it moves line by line. The correct answer is from Viral Modi

Answer (score 6):

**<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> Arrow key** do Page up and Page down respectively in IntelliJ running on OS X. 
This is one of the standard ways of doing Page Up/Page Down in Mac apart from Option Up and Down arrow key that you mentioned.

Comment: Your answer is similar to the one from @msoliman: it is not incorrect but as mentioned I prefer not to use `function` key for basic cursor movements

Comment: My bad. I missed the second answer and your response there. If you are a touch typer, pressing Fn key with your left hand pinky and arrow with your right hand pinky should   help keep your finger aligned.

Comment: um yea - I were not going to do it with my right thumb .. you must have more agile hands than me: for operations that are done so frequently I find that reaching the `fn` key (with the pinky ..) is awkward.

Answer (score 4):

It was annoying for me to find out which keys to get the cursor or caret up or down quickly or may be to the end or beginning of current line till I figured out the following shortcuts that might help:

`Fn+Left arrow` or `Ctrl+A` move the cursor to the end of current line.

`Fn+Right arrow` or `Ctrl+E` move the cursor to the beginning of current line.

`Fn+Up arrow` or `Fn+Cmd+Left` move the cursor to the beginning of the file.

`Fn+Down arrow` or `Fn+Cmd+Right` move the cursor to the end of the file.

Comment: I hear you - but using the Function key for basic cursor movement is for me a non-starter.